# Passing html control id to javascript from aspx file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm amazed I haven't found an answer to this yet. I'm using a standard html button (as opposed to an asp:Button) in an ASPX file. When calling a javascript function from the onclick attribute, if the javascript call contains a variable, it fails. For example, `onclick="func1()"` will run perfectly, however, `onclick="func2(this.id)"`, doesn't. I understand that `this.id` shouldn't work in an asp:Button, but should it fail in a standard html button?

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<button id="Hour" type="button" class="butshape" onclick="return middlePress(this.id)" disabled></button>
```

Javascript:

```
function middlePress(clicked_id){
    document.getElementById("lengthtext").innerHTML=clicked_id;
    clearEnd();
    switch(clicked_id){
        case "Day":
            document.getElementById("11").innerHTML=Date();
            document.getElementById("12").innerHTML="Previous 24";
            document.getElementById("12").disabled=false;
            break;
        case "Week":
            document.getElementById("11").innerHTML=Date();
            document.getElementById("12").innerHTML="Previous 7 Days";
            document.getElementById("12").disabled=false;
            break;
        case "Month":
            document.getElementById("11").innerHTML=Date();
            document.getElementById("12").innerHTML="Previous 30 Days";
            document.getElementById("12").disabled=false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. What your console says? http://jsfiddle.net/hadyg1za/

Comment: Upload the relevant source code and we have something to debug. Without the source code we have nothing to debug meaning we have no answers for you.

Comment: show your function definition and html code for button creation

Comment: Is hard to know if you don't show your log about what error is throwing, you can also debug it step by step in chrome console `f12`. you can also try to use events to trigger your function instead of using the `onclick` html atributte, something like `object.onclick=function(){myScript};`

Comment: I've run the html/javascript outside of asp.net and it works fine. When compiled in VS this function just doesn't execute for some reason...

Comment: Your button is disabled.

Comment: button is disabled then how can you click on that ?

Comment: Yerko - I didn't know you could step through like that! Thanks,

Comment: Sorry - the button is enabled elsewhere - there is a lot of code, i posted what i thought was relevant. I've stepped through it now, the error its giving is TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use an `asp:button` and add your Js function to that element, like said in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k(v=vs.140).aspx). Check that link, here is the code.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">
    Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = "Server click handler called."
    End Sub
</script>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" 
      OnClick="Button1_Click" 
      OnClientClick="return confirm('Ready to submit.');" 
      Text="Test Client Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Runat="server" text="" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Now that you have uploaded something for us to work with I have your source code working.

I have also change the `ID` of the button to match in your switch case.
The button `id` in your source code didn't match anything so to make sure it all worked I changed it.

```js
function middlePress(clicked_id){
    document.getElementById("lengthtext").innerHTML=clicked_id;
    switch(clicked_id){
        case "Day":
            document.getElementById("11").innerHTML=Date();
            document.getElementById("12").innerHTML="Previous 24";
            document.getElementById("12").disabled=false;
            break;
        case "Week":
            document.getElementById("11").innerHTML=Date();
            document.getElementById("12").innerHTML="Previous 7 Days";
            document.getElementById("12").disabled=false;
            break;
        case "Month":
            document.getElementById("11").innerHTML=Date();
            document.getElementById("12").innerHTML="Previous 30 Days";
            document.getElementById("12").disabled=false;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="Day" type="button" class="butshape" onclick="return middlePress(this.id)" >Click me</button>
<div id="lengthtext"></div>
<div id="11"></div>
<button id="12" disabled>Button 12</button>
```

I hope this helps. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

In you code the button is disabled Then the `click event` will not work

Try following

It should be work

**html**

```
<input type="button" id="Hour"  class="butshape" onclick=" middlePress(this.id)" value="button">
```

**javascript**

```
function  middlePress(id)
{
alert(id);
}
```

You can check here here is working example in fiddle
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ptmdmb9/1/)**